# Error in signal.c when compile qemu-xen

Tags: c++, c, signals, qemu, xen

I got an error when building `tools/qemu-xen` in xen-4.2.3.

It conplains when I `make` `qemu-xen`:

```
/home/xen/xen-4.2.3/tools/qemu-xen/linux-user/signal.c:3468:24: error: field ‘info’ has incomplete type
make[1]: *** [signal.o] Error 1
make: *** [subdir-cris-linux-user] Error 2
```

And that is the source code:

```
3465 struct rt_signal_frame {
3466         struct siginfo *pinfo;
3467         void *puc;
3468         struct siginfo info;
3469         struct ucontext uc;
3470         uint8_t retcode[8];       /* Trampoline code. */
3471 };
```

I cant find anything improper and the most wired thing is field `info` is not the first reference to `siginfo`, why it doesnt complain for `*pinfo`(at 3466)?

I also tried in xen-4.2.2 and it turned out the same. Both compilation was made on official tarball. Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

Comment: It doesn't complain for `pinfo` because that's a pointer. In C, you can safely create a pointer to an incomplete type, because the only thing the compiler needs to know for that is the size of the pointer, not the size of the thing pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

It complains for this line:

```
 3468         struct siginfo info;
```

Did you do

```
 #include <siginfo.h>
```

somewhere before your compilation unit? And is this in your include path?